# Importing & Extending raw CSS?

Tags: css, less

I have a preprocessor import problem. I have vendor css that i would like to copy functionality. Unfortunately, *i don't control the html* for this situation either.. so essentially i have vendor css & different vendor html, and i am trying to extend functionality of one css rule into another.

Now, the basic concept in many css preprocessors is to extend the rule.

```
// Vendor
.foo { font-weight: bold; }
.bar { text-color: red; }

// Mine
.bar { .foo }
```

In the above example, you don't have access to `.foo` or `.bar`, but with preprocessors, you can extend functionality from `.foo` into `.bar`, which works great for less/stylus/etc. The problem, is when the vendor rules are only defined in raw css.

So with that said, the most obvious solution is to have Stylus/Less import the raw css as stylus/less. However, neither seem to be able to actually do this.. that i've found at least. Less doesn't seem able to *(`@import "foo.css"` directives are ignored)* and while Stylus has an option to actually include the imported raw CSS, it did not seem to actually be processing it. That is to say, it would include the css, but `@extend` directives failed *(perhaps i am wrong?)*.

The other option i could think of is simply renaming the .css files to the preprocessor language extension. Since we want to keep the vendor stuff out of our hands, allowing for proper versioning/etc, This involves a build process which copies the target css files and renames them into the target language extension, but this is error prone. Stylus ran into syntax errors immediately, and Less could just as easily *(as not all CSS is valid Less. most is, but not all)*.

So.. any additional thoughts on this front? Hopefully there is an option i may be missing? Perhaps SCSS handles this better?

Currently, with what i have found is/isn't possible.. i feel the only *stable* way is to simply copy the raw css bits into my css code. If the vendor code changes, i'll have to update manually, but at least i don't run the risk of vendor stuff changing and all of a sudden the build process fails, because vendor introduced some CSS syntax not supported by less/etc. It is far from good.. but the worst that can happen is my css looks funny, and i need to update.

**edit**:

I'm going to try SCSS next.. we'll see how it goes. On the site, they claim all CSS(3 only?) syntax is valid SCSS

**edit2:** For clarity. My question is, give the above scenario, what would *you* do? Importing the .css files is not possible **(See note below!)**, and renaming .css files to .less/.stylus can in turn be error prone, since less is not a perfect superset of CSS(namely due to proprietary features).

**!Note!**: I have since been digging around the less source to see what could be done to fix this problem, rather than work around it, and ran into a dozen support tickets on the matter. The main discussion of which seems to be taking place on [#issue 1185](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1185), and more importantly, check out the changelog which *(i believe) addresses this issue! [CHANGELOG 1.4.0 Beta](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

So with that said, the `@import (less) "file.css"` is likely the winning scenario here, even if it may have a few bugs due to the beta status. Yay :)

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While still in beta, the newly added `@import (less) "file.css"` syntax should properly handle all CSS files. Due to the "official" support, it can also be expected/assumed that any proprietary syntax that breaks LESS would be fixed *(though possibly not "supported")*.

So in theory this is the best option! Barring SCSS, which i have not tried yet in this scenario. Stylus still has issues though, in my tests.

For more information, check out [this issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1185) or [this changelog](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is either what @Lee Olayvar said, or use the new ":extend()" feature in LESS. It sounds like you might have tried the extend feature, but you used the "SASS directive" syntax (which IMO is improper use of an at-rule), whereas LESS uses the CSS-like pseudo-selector syntax:

```
.foo:extend(.bar) {}
```

And if you are patient (in the coming days/weeks), you will see a new feature that is **perfect** for what you want to do, and it's unique to LESS. **It will allow you to extend or mixin external "silent" styles**. Meaning you will be able to "@import" and external stylesheet but the styles won't show up in your compiled code unless you extend them or use them as a mixin.

I'm on the core team for Less.js btw, so let me know if you have any other questions or if I can be of further help.

Comment: Ah, well the OP and Lee Olayvar is indeed, me. haha. I was going to mark my answer as the "Answer" *(I have to wait 48 hours to do so)*, but you have provided some good additional insight! I was using the Mixin feature, as per the [docs, here](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins). I'll checkout :extend as well! Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Lol, I didn't notice that it was you! Mixins are good too, but extend has the same benefit without copying all of the properties to the "new" selector. Hope this helps, as long as I'm clear on what you're looking for I can try to tell you the best way to do it.

Comment: Yea, extend is far better than mixin for my use case. In this specific example, i still want to import the full styles *(rather than silent styles)*, but silent styles are an awesome feature!

Comment: Well the cool thing is that you can both either, or both. So what I meant was that _if you want them to be silent_, you would do `@import (silent) "styles.less";` but you can extend them either way, silent or not.

Comment: A note to anyone coming on this post in the future, `.foo:extend(.bar) {}` is the correct syntax. The argument to `extend()` does not need quotes. I would edit the original post, but StackOverflow requires 6 characters to be a valid edit.. odd. So yea, just an fyi :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all imported `.css` files won't be prepocessed by `less` but will just be added with an `@import` at the top.

> You can import both CSS and LESS files. Only LESS files import statements are processed, CSS file import statements are kept as they are. If you want to import a CSS file, and don’t want LESS to process it, just use the .css extension

**Source: http://lesscss.org/**

The best thing you could do would be the renaming I believe.

Comment: Renaming poses the issue that both LESS and Stylus have though, in that all CSS is not Valid LESS. Unless they have changed something recently, that is. So using this method would be prone to a possible build process issue in the future if you introduce a new vendor file and/or a vendor adds unsupported syntax.

Comment: I don't see why `CSS` wouldn't be valid `LESS`? As far as I know you can still use brackets if you want so it would be valid?

Comment: I think some of the weird stuff like proprietary IE filters have to be escaped a special way in LESS.

Comment: Yes, it's "some of the weird proprietary stuff" that isn't valid in LESS. To my knowledge, Microsoft has some, and Webkit has some. Not sure about Mozilla. Either way, in the end that means that there are some CSS syntaxes that are out of my control that *may* break my build process. I'd prefer to find a way that is assured to work.

Comment: Though, it's hard to say if SCSS and LESS break in the same ways (MS/Webkit proprietary stuff)